# Relation between two sets (union and intersection)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, set-theory

I tried to approach this problem by assuming some $x$ belongs to the right side, and then getting to the left side, and vice versa, but I can't get any relation between the two sets. The question is as follows:

Let $A_{i}$, for $i$ element of $\mathbb{N}$, be different sets. Determine the relation between the sets:
$$(\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n) \setminus (\displaystyle\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n)$$ and $$\displaystyle\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} (A_{n+1} \setminus A_n)$$

Any ideas will be helpful, thank you!

Comment: Have you tried some specific choices of $A_n$? If your first choice yields one side as a proper subset of the other, then try to find a different choice for which it isn't a subset of the other.  If you can, then you have shown that neither is necessarily contained in the other. If you cannot, that will suggest what the relation is, and hopefully give intuition for how to prove it.

Comment: Let the two sets in question be $X$ and $Y$. The questions they're asking are: is it the case that $X \subseteq Y$? Is it the case that $Y \subseteq X$?

Comment: That's what I was going for, but then I didn't know how to continue solving the exercise, because I wasn't getting anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty immediate that the first set contains the second by observing the following: If $x \in A_{n+1} \setminus A_n$ for some $n$, then $x \in \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$, while $x \notin \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n$.

Suppose $A_n$ are subsets of the natural numbers, and in particular, $A_n = \{n\}$. Then $A_2 \setminus A_1 = \{2\}$, and $A_3 \setminus A_2 = \{3\}$, and so on, so $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (A_{n+1} \setminus A_n) = \{2,3,...\}$, while $$(\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) \setminus (\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n) = \{1,2,3,..\} \setminus \varnothing = \{1,2,3,...\}$$ so the second set does not necessarily contain the first set. I was trying to see if I could prove the sets must be equal, but it turns out there is an easy counterexample to this.